# Coopers australian stout - Replacing white sugar, no spraymalt or brewing sugar

Tags: stout, sugar, kits, substitution, coopers

I have the white coopers australian stout 23L kit which recommends the additional 1kg sugar you can add but I know its not recommended. I know most people add 1kg spraymalt but I do not have it right now, or any brewing sugar (and won't be able to get more for a while). I was wondering how 500g or 1kg of 'caramel sugar' or brown sugar would taste. Is another alternative to just reduce the amount of wort I make? I've used 1kg white sugar with a bitter/pale ale in the past and it tasted fine. This kit is apparently very bitter.

thank you for any help.

Comment: When I was using kits + sugar it didn't taste really great, but maybe I was doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a stout that would be fine, since the roastiness of the brew will overpower any residual sweetness, and color change will not be noticable. Any caramel flavors that do come through will be a positive bonus to offset the bitterness of the kit.

There's no problem using regular table sugar with these kits, although using spraymalt/DME  will enhance the malt qualities of the brew.

In your position I'd probably do 500g of white table sugar and 500g of brown sugar. So you get some dryness from the table sugar, and a little extra flavour from the brown sugar.

Comment: Your welcome. Thanks for accepting the answer, but just to let you and other new users know - it's often a good idea to wait a day or two to let several answers roll in - brewing is an art - often there are many right answers! Good luck with the brew.

Comment: I understand, will do so in future. thank you.